# How to use one button to calculate and validate via javascript and then submit and navigate

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a js-function `codeAddress()` which completes an address via google maps javascript api and sets a global js-variable `valid = true`, if the full address was recognized. It also updates the value of a `<p:inputText>` with the completed address.

Now I have one `<p:commandButton>` that I want to

1. execute `codeAddress()`
2. if `valid = true` submit form so address in `<p:inputText>` is saved in `addressBean` and
3. navigate to next page
4. if `valid = false` trigger jsf-validator messages

Unfortunately my setup still does not work with `valid` as the essential value to determine if next page. It seems, that the value is submitted to bean too late.

this is my jsf code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="bugMaps.js" />
    <body onload="initialize()" />
    <h:form id="addressForm" onsubmit="codeAddress();">
        <p:inputText id="address" required="true"
            validatorMessage="Please enter a valid address." validator="#{addressBean.validate()}">
            <p:ajax update=":addressForm:addressValidate" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:message id="addressValidate" for=":addressForm:address"/>
        <p:commandButton value="submit"
            onclick="codeAddress();"/>
        <p:inputText id="fullAddress" value="#{addressBean.fullAddress}" />
        <p:inputText id="valid" value="#{addressBean.valid}" />
    </h:form>   
</h:body>
</html>
```

this is the bugMaps.js:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var valid;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeAddress() {

    var address = (document.getElementById('addressForm:address').value + ", Germany");
    geocoder.geocode({'address' : address},function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLong = results[0].geometry.location;
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var country, postal_code, locality, street_number, route;
            for (i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; ++i) {
                var component = results[0].address_components[i];
                if (!locality && component.types.indexOf("locality") > -1)
                    locality = component.long_name;
                else if (!postal_code && component.types.indexOf("postal_code") > -1)
                    postal_code = component.long_name;
                else if (!country && component.types.indexOf("country") > -1)
                    country = component.long_name;
                else if (!street_number && component.types.indexOf("street_number") > -1)
                    street_number = component.long_name;
                else if (!route && component.types.indexOf("route") > -1)
                    route = component.long_name;
            }

            if (typeof latLong != "undefined"
                && typeof latitude != "undefined"
                && typeof longitude != "undefined"
                && typeof route != "undefined"
                && typeof street_number != "undefined"
                && typeof postal_code != "undefined"
                && typeof locality != "undefined"
                && typeof country != "undefined"){
                valid = true;

            }
            else{
                valid=false;
            };
            document.getElementById('addressForm:fullAddress').value = results[0].formatted_address;

            jsfSubmit();

        }
        else{
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: '+ status);
            valid=false;

        }
    }); 
};

function navigateToAnotherPage(data){
    if(valid){
        document.location.href='nextPage.xhtml';
    }
};

function jsfSubmit(){
    jsf.ajax.request(this, event, {execute:"@form", onevent:navigateToAnotherPage});
    alert("nothing"); // FIXME: without this useful alert bean keeps old values and display them on nextPage
};
```

this is my AddressBean.java:

```
package hoho.main.managebean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.sun.faces.util.MessageFactory;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class AddressBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String fullAddress;
    private boolean valid = false;

    public void validate(FacesContext context,
            UIComponent toValidate, Object value) {
        if(!valid){
              String client = toValidate.getClientId(context);  
              FacesMessage msg = MessageFactory.getMessage(UIInput.REQUIRED_MESSAGE_ID, client);  
              throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }

    public String getFullAddress() {
        return fullAddress;
    }

    public void setFullAddress(String fullAddress) {
        this.fullAddress = fullAddress;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    public void setValid(boolean valid) {
        this.valid = valid;
    }

}
```

this is the nextPage.xhtml:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:outputText value="#{addressBean.fullAddress}" />

</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsf.ajax.request` in your javascript to submit your form. An example is

```
        function navigateToAnotherPage(data){
            //When the request is completed, we are safe to navigate to another page.
            if(data.status == "success"){
                alert("callback is invoked");
                //Go to another page
                document.location.href='destpage.xhtml';
            }
        }

        function jsfSubmit(){
            alert("Do your logic here");
            jsf.ajax.request(this, event, {execute:"@form", onevent:navigateToAnotherPage});
        }
```

And bind this function to a jsf component

```
        <h:commandButton type="button" value="javascriptSubmit" onclick="jsfSubmit()"/>
```

A complete reference is here:http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/js-api/symbols/jsf.ajax.html

However, I don't know how to call a backing bean method through javascript. So I always use two buttons. The javascript process logic when I click the first button , and after that it trigger the click event on the second button that submits the form and navigate to another page. And of course the second button would be `display:none`. Also, it is kinda simpler.

Besides, the validation does not work because validation always happen before the backing bean is updated. I don't see any link between the javascript `var valid` in javascript and the `boolean valid` in the backing bean. Howver, if you update `<p:inputText id="valid" value="#{addressBean.valid}" />` using javascript, submit the input field, update the backing bean `valid` and use this boolean variable for validation, then the validation will always fail. This is because before `boolean valid` is updated (for example, true), the validation method is first called(so the validation method may be using an out-of-date `valid`.

The walk around would be, you attach the validator to `<p:inputText id="valid" value="#{addressBean.valid}" />` rather than `<p:inputText id="address" required="true"...../>`. Now, you can get the value of the input field using `value` in `validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent toValidate, Object value)`. The value here is the value you put(or javascript put) in the input field on the page (and therefore it is always up-to-date).

Please note that, by this time the `valid` in the backing bean is not updated yet. If the validation is OK, then `valid` is updated and set to `value` you just got. If the validation fails, then `valid` is not updated.

In a word, the flow would be, 0. build/restore the component tree. 1. conversion, validation. 2. update the values in the backing bean. 3. call backing bean method 4. render the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which already helped me a lot. I did not use a second button as I integrated your functions to be called by `codeAddress()` if `valid = true`. `fullAddress` is already saved to the backing bean by submit of the form, which works due to your functions.

Comment: What still lacks is a working validation. When I have the `<p:commandButton>`'s `onclick`-event as I do, it seems, that nothing happens. The value of the global js-variable `valid` is responsible if validation passes or fails. I just don't know how to get it working with jsf/primefaces-validation.

Comment: Strange: On the first attempt after server restart `fullAddress` seems not to be saved to the backing bean on form submit. When I enter a new address on initial page and proceed this value appears on the next page as it should (from backing bean).

Comment: Thank you again. I got it now. Unfortunately `jsf.ajax.request` is hardly cross-browser compatible. I do the same but use jQuery now.

Comment: Hi @Lester Sorry for this very late reply. Went for a holiday this month and just returned. `data.status == "success"` is used to make sure that the form is submitted to the bean first before the rest of code/logic is executed. the `onevent:navigateToAnotherPage` means that `navigateToAnotherPage` is executed three times, and the first time is when the form submission request is just sent. That means just after you send the request, the navigation logic is executed. This should be the reason why it looks that form is submitted too late.

Comment: Wow, that was a great help again! It worked on first try, although I use a jQuery ajax request for easy cross-browser compatibility because e.g. firefox throws `Error: ReferenceError: event is not defined` with the above one. Only thing that still bugs me: I am updating the `<p:message>` with a `<p:remoteCommand>` triggered by my JS and I just can't come up with a simpler solution.

Comment: hmm, and I would have to abstain from a required validation before the user bugs google maps api, right?

Comment: Its like 1.javascript-2.submit form/ajax submit-3.jsf validation(e.g. required or custom validation). In this case, the `required="true"` validation happens in the third phase. You can do validation in both javascript and jsf validation at the same time . If the api I am using in backing bean(jsf, or ejb) is robust and can handle an empty input, then I usually prefer to do the validation in the javascript part`onclick=validateAndAjaxSubmit`. 
However, if the api crashes when empty input is submit. Then I will have an `required="true"` to guard the cases in which a user disable/hack javascript.